# Map Loads; Overlays load; Map responds to jscripts... but map.DrawingManager is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a portal that I'm working on redesigning: it uses Google Maps as a base layer, then overlays a series of different layers that represent planning zones, planning overlays, government authority area boundaries and so forth.

These overlays, and mechanisms to make them

- visible
- selectable (to fetch data about them for reporting) and
- to set the transparency of each layer

  are loaded and manipulated by a series of javascript scripts.

There is also a javascript that generates a **toolbar** for zooming, panning, and circle/polygon selection within the map canvas, and another that enables **reports** to be generated for a subset of the data, and a subset of the government regions.

All of this worked fine: the decision to make the presentation layer more 'modern' was driven in part by a project to update the underlying data.

The layout of the portal was a bit of a schemozzle - a lot of stuff placed with 'absolute' positioning and so forth (plus, the dominant colour was orange), which made it look like a dog's breakfast if your screen was <27" (I guess the original dev had one of those).

So I began shifting stuff around, and got the layout heading towards something sensible.

I now find that the overwhelming bulk of the javascript functionality works exactly as it did in the past, with two exceptions: the reporting, and the toolbar.

All of the javascript stuff gets triggered by a script that is run via `window.onload = InitialisePortal`.

`InitialisePortal()` calls a series of functions that initialise components: the base map is the first thing initialised, and the toolbar is constructed and placed subsequent to that.

The base map loads, and can be changed by javascript `onclick()`: for instance there are buttons that

- zoom to a selected government area;
- make the base map an aerial; and
- make the base map monochrome instead of colour.

These all work exactly as they did.

On the reporting side, a 'drop-down' selector fails to populate, and so all functionality stops there. I'm not that worried about the reporting side just yet.

On the 'toolbar' side, the toolbar is built, and is placed where it ought to be; but none of the button functionality works.

The javascripts are all in exactly the same part of the page, in exactly the same order, as the old version.

The relevant `div`'s in the HTML are in the same relative position (i.e., the order of `div`s in the page source has not changed). The CSS for some `div`s has changed - but only `position: absolute` (etc) and `background-color`. The map is in a `div` with `id="map_canvas"` as you might expect.

**CLUES.**

The first clue: `TypeError: a is null in main.js:18:0` (main.js from maps.gstatic.com). That would seem to indicate that some variable that `main` expected, was not passed.

The second clue: `map.drawingManager is undefined in ToolBarControl.js:229:3`.

ToolBarControl.js line 229 is `map.drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null)`

*map.drawingManager* is defined in *Portal-Drawing.js* line 6 - `map.drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager([snip]`

`map` is defined in *Portal-Main.js* line 382 - 
`map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);`

My diagnosis is that somehow `main.js` knows enough about the map to be able to do all the stuff that works, but somehow drops the ball on the drawingManager side of things.

So finally the question: has anybody seen the specific (i.e., main.js **line 18** - i.e., `function Ze(a,b)`) undefined-a problem before? If so, what does it mean?

(I am assuming that null `a` is the cause of subsequent problems with defining map.drawingManager(), too).

For those who want to peruse the (old, orange) version (which works perfectly) and the (25% finished, blue) version (where the toolbar is *verkakte*); they are here -

[Existing (working) version](http://map.spatialeconomics.com.au/g21)

[Development Version](http://map.spatialeconomics.com.au/g21/GT_index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no elements(radioButtons) with the IDs `changetype-establishment` and `changetype-geocode`. The error is forced by the attempt to add an eventListener to these undefined elements in `setupClickListener`(G21_Portal-SearchBar_src.js)

Fix this error(add the elements or remove the calls of `setupClickListener`) and the other error will went away too.